# google maps mousemove and click listener together

Tags: google-maps, addeventlistener

I use a mousemove listener on Google Maps, while I want handle the click event too.

```
var path = new google.maps.MVCArray;
...
line = new google.maps.Polyline({
  map: map,
  path: new google.maps.MVCArray([path]),
});
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
   path.push(event.latLng);
});
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'mousemove', function(event) {
  if (path.getLength() > 1) path.setAt(path.getLength()-1,event.latLng);
});
```

I want to follow the mouse with the line, but if the user click on the map, push the polyline's array. But the click event doesn't work...
Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a small bug in your code:

On line 5 it should read

```
path: path,
```

instead of

```
path: new google.maps.MVCArray([path]),
```

**Reason:**
Your var *path* is already an MCVArray and the property *path* of *PolylineOptions* expects just an MVCArray, but you supply it with an MVCArray inside a normal array inside an MVCArray.

This prevents the code following from pushing the coordinates to the correct array.